# Unicode-math changes font outside of range

Tags: fonts, unicode-math

I'm using the `unicode-math` package with LuaLaTeX (TeXlive 2017). I'm trying to set the math font for the `\setminus` character [as in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326455/latin-modern-math-and-setminus), because it doesn't exist in the Latin Modern math font.

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
\[ \pi \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \]
\end{document}
```

I get this result:

[image: result with no second setmathfont]

As expected, the `\setminus` character doesn't appear, and I have the Latin Modern font.

But now if I try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\setminus]{XITS Math} % This changed
\begin{document}
\[ \pi \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \]
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

The `\setminus` character now appears, but the mathbb font changed! And if I try with random letters (or the `\pi` character above), I see that the "normal" font remains Latin Modern. What happened?

Comment: The bug has been fixed with `unicode-math` version 0.8j, released 2018-01-07.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is one of the side effects of the range option - it is a bit buggy. Reset things to your main font afterwards. I would also use \symbb instead of \mathbb -- it is the more modern and semantic correct command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\setminus]{XITS Math} % This changed
\setmathfont[range=\int]{Latin Modern Math} % This changed
\begin{document}
\[ \pi \in \symbb{R} \setminus \symbb{Q} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between mathbb and symbb? I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: The sym** commands take the glyph from the relevant unicode block of the current math font, while the math** commands (can) use a different font (even a textfont). So I would use \sym** for all normal single glyphs variables from the set [a-Z].