# Bug with \setmathfont range?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, unicode-math, libertine

I am using XeLaTeX and unicode-math with the Libertinus Math font. Some symbols are missing therefore I'm using the *range* command. Then I get an unwanted crossed-square symbol beside big curly braces. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range={\rightrightarrows,\twoheadrightarrow}]{xits-math.otf}
% The seemingly useleess command below is needed for a different known bug
\setmathfont[range={\int}]{Libertinus Math}
\begin{document}
\[
\Bigl\{\Bigr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Known bug in the comment above: [Unicode-math changes font outside of range](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383159/unicode-math-changes-font-outside-of-range)

Does anybody know if this is a known bug? Is there a solution?

**EDIT**: I just found a workaround [here](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/344). Is there a "cleaner" solution?

Comment: The bug has been fixed with `unicode-math` version 0.8j, released 2018-01-07.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reset the delcode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range={\rightrightarrows,\twoheadrightarrow}]{xits-math.otf}
% The seemingly useleess command below is needed for a different known bug
\setmathfont[range={\int}]{Libertinus Math}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\__um_set_delcode:nnn {operators} {`\.} {\c_zero}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\[
\Bigl\{\Bigr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

But it would be better if this were corrected in unicode-math (or xetex if it indicates a xetex bug).

Comment: Thanks, I'm hoping to look into all of these problems shortly...

Comment: @WillRobertson On the whole I think it is a xetex peculiarity. It seems to handle the dot in the operators family (fam0? I never remember this) differently than in other families. So it is probably best to hardcode this delcode.

Comment: — I remember hardcoding this already in general (inside `\wspr81@gmail.com_setup_delcodes:` in the source) so I suspect you're right that hardcoding it for `operators` and so on is also needed.